# What does the curly-brace syntax ${var%.*} mean?

Tags: bash, syntax

I was reviewing some of my old code and came across this syntax:

```
extractDir="${downloadFileName%.*}-tmp"
```

The only information I found searching refers to a list of commands, but this is just one variable. **What does this curly-brace syntax mean in bash?**

Comment: Start with *the comprehensive* [BASH Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) ... It is covered under [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). (The curly braces mean something else when *not* preceded with the `$` symbol.)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In this context, it is a [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

The `${variable%.*}` notation means take the value of `$variable`, strip off the pattern `.*` from the tail of the value — mnemonic: percenT has a 't' at the Tail — and give the result.  (By contrast, `${variable#xyz}` means remove `xyz` from the head of the variable's value — mnemonic: a Hash has an 'h' at the Head.)

Given:

```
downloadFileName=abc.tar.gz
```

evaluating `extractDir="${downloadFileName%.*}-tmp"` yields the equivalent of:

```
extractDir="abc.tar-tmp"
```

The alternative notation with the double `%`:

```
extractDir="${downloadFileName%%.*}-tmp"
```

would yield the equivalent of:

```
extractDir="abc-tmp"
```

The `%%` means remove the longest possible tail; correspondingly, `##` means remove the longest matching head.

Comment: @Shane: Are you sure?  In Bash?  My almost fully-patched Bash 4.3 (4.3.27(2)) on Mac OS X 10.10 doesn't like it: `downloadFileName=abc.tar.gz; echo ${${downloadFileName#abc.}%.gz}` generates: `bash-4.3: ${${downloadFileName#abc.}%.gz}: bad substitution`.  Can you specify which platform and which version of Bash?

Comment: In Zsh (**not Bash**), these can also be nested (i.e. ${${downloadFilename#abc.}%.gz} yields "tar"). Thanks @JonathanLeffler for the catch.

Comment: Your example is not quite right.

`> downloadFileName=abc.tar.gz`

`> echo ${downloadFileName}`
**abc.tar.gz**

`> echo ${downloadFileName%.*}`
**abc.tar**

`> echo ${downloadFileName%%.*}`
**abc**

Comment: @Declan: Thank you — you were right that the example material wasn't as clear as it should have been. I hope the changes make it clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

It indicates that [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) will occur.

Answer (score -1):

It is used when expanding an environment variable adjacent to some text that is not the variable, so the shell does not include all of it in the variable name.

Comment: That misses several points: (1) the notation is used with ordinary variables too — it is not only environment variables that use the notation; and (2) the `%` etc has special significance — it is not part of the variable name.