# unhide hidden files in unix with sed and mv commands

Tags: regex, bash, sed, mv, hidden-files

i wonder if u could help me with fixing bash script which should unhide all hiden files in dir.
Where is the problem?

```
param='.'
for file in $param*; do
mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/^.\(.*\)/\1/')
done
exit
```

Answer (score 7):

This `for loop` should work:

```
export GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
for file in .*; do
   mv -n "$file" "${file#.}"
   # mv -n "$file" "${file:1}"
done
```

**PS:** Better to backup your files before doing a mass mv/rename

Comment: Won't this try to rename `.` and `..` as well ?

Comment: anubhava could u explain ur that mv line? It is working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also have written `mv "$file" "${file:1}"`

Comment: See, amongst other places, [What does the curly brace syntax mean in `bash`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558986/what-does-the-curly-brace-syntax-mean-in-bash/9559024#9559024)

Comment: You could also `export GLOBIGNORE=".:.."` in your script, then using `.*` will skip those.

Comment: @user2988575: `"${file#.}"` removes first dot from the input string. Yes you can also use `"${file:1}"` which means substring from 1st character onwards (discarding 0th position dot)

Comment: Might also want to `test -e "${file#.}"` before moving another file on top of an existing one. ;-)

Comment: @Mike: Thanks I made it `mv -n` to skip overwriting an existing file.

Comment: @Mike: While `export GLOBIGNORE=".:.."` is arguably a reasonable global default, it should be noted that you're changing *global* state with it - which may have unintended effects on subsequent commands. To safely localize the effect of setting `GLOBIGNORE`, drop the `export` and enclose the entire block (assigning to `GLOBIGNORE`, plus the `for` loop) in parentheses.

Comment: @mklement0 what was I thinking.  `.[^.] .??*`.

Comment: @jthill: Your thinking was promising - provide a self-contained pattern expression that doesn't rely on global state (`GLOBIGNORE`) - it *almost* works, if it weren't for the duplicates. (To correct my earlier comment: unfortunately, you don't get a strict union in a set-theory sense, but a *multiset*.)

Comment: @mklement0 This one gets dups?  I can't see it, can you provide an example?  Btw, none of the examples here work reliably without `shopt -s nullglob`, which I think also isn't a default. With `GLOBIGNORE` and no dotfiles you get `.*`

Comment: @mklement0 ah, no, I was referring to the corrected pair w/o the brainfart, `.[^.] .??*`. Either way, I'm pretty sure we've covered this exhaustively :-)

Comment: Good point re `shopt -s nullglob`. Your corrected pattern - `.[^.] .??*` - indeed works correctly (but also needs `shopt -s nullglob`). See my answer for a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava's answer works, but here's an **amended, generalized solution for processing hidden files/folders**, which:

- correctly deals with edge cases (the absence of hidden files/folders).
- neither depends on nor alters global state (configuration).

  ```
  ( # Execute in subshell to localize configuration changes below.
  GLOBIGNORE=".:.."   # Do not match '.' and '..'.
  shopt -s nullglob   # Expand globbing pattern to empty string, if no matches.
  for f in .*; do     # Enumerate all hidden files/folders, if any.
    # Process "$f" here; e.g.: mv -n "$f" "${f:1}"
  done
  )
  ```

If you want to **avoid a subshell**, you can use the following approach, which explicitly rules out `.` and `..` and also an unexpanded pattern in case there are no matches (if `GLOBIGNORE` happens to contain `.:..`):

```
    for f in .*; do
     if [[ $f != '.' && $f != '..'  && -e $f ]]; then
        # Process "$f" here; e.g.: mv -n "$f" "${f:1}"
     fi
    done
```

Tip of the hat to @jthill, @anubhava, @Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mass-rename them like that myself, I'd add visible symbolic links to them:

```
while read f; do
        ln -s "$f" "visible-${f#./}"
done <<EOD
$(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*')
EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only unhide all hidden files, keep away from your home directory!!!

```
ls -1Ap |grep "^\." |grep -v "/" |while read F; do mv $F ${F:1}; done
```

This will unhide all hidden files and dirs, again: keep away from your home directory!!!

```
ls -1A |grep "^\." |while read F; do mv $F ${F:1}; done
```

Best you can do to test these kind of dangerous games is to make yourself an extra account on your machine...If you screw up your own account there will be "tears unlimited(tm)"

If you want to test it first (which is a VERY sensible thing to do):

```
ls -1A |grep "^\." |while read F; do echo "mv $F ${F:1}"; done
```